# sending message by user id in c# bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

i'm trying to send message to People user name for example my friends username is @...
but no thing happend 
no Error
and no send 
can i use this library ?
or just with tlsharp?
how can i found apiid and hashid for my bot?

using Telegram.Bot;

and

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       Telegram.Bot. TelegramBotClient bot = new TelegramBotClient("token");

        Thread a;
             public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void GetUpdates()
        {
            int offset = 0;
            while (true)
            {

                Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[] updates = 
                 bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset).Result;

                foreach (var update in updates)
                {

                    offset = update.Id + 1;
                    if (update.Message == null)
                        continue;

                    var from = update.Message.From.FirstName;
                    var text = update.Message.Text;
                   string  chatid = update.Message.Chat.Id;
                    string username = update.Message.From.Username;
                    // label1.BeginInvoke(delegate { label1.Text = label1.BeginInvoke(delegate { label1.Text = string.Format("sender:{0}\ntext:{1}\ncatid:{2}", from, text, chatid); }); });
                  // lblshow.Text = string.Format("sender:{0}\ntext:{1}\ncatid:{2}", from, text, chatid);
                  //label1.Text = string.Format("sender:{0}\ntext:{1}\ncatid:{2}", from, text, chatid);
                    this.BeginInvoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate () {textBox1.Text = string.Format("sender:{0}\ntext:{1}\ncusername:{2}", from, text, username); });
                  bot.SendTextMessageAsync( chatid, "سلام بر شما");
                    //is this correct for send to people? 
                    bot.SendTextMessageAsync("@Hoda.....", "hi");


                }




            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant send message to user by user Name.telegram bot API only accept user Id. (except channels).

Comment: david i need you help related on telegram bot so can i aksing?

Comment: Hello david i have one bot on the telegram. and in the bot i want to show list of doctor name and any user go in the bot select any doctor name and that time on the bot chating will be start with the dr, so it's possible on the bot?? using c#. i am more suffering fotr that task. i am try many links find but not getting success so can you please help me

Comment: hello dear @Edit. its completely unrelated to this topic. please consider asking new question so we can help you. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i am asking like this question few hours ago but some user put on hold and give me minus vote.i have post like this question just i have no idea how can do that. it's possible or not i have not idea. i don't know how to start code also. so i am asking direct in personal comment.

Comment: Hello  david i am getting one error "Request timed out" like this for image send time on telegram bot using c#? are you aware with this error to?

Comment: as i told you that's not a best way to ask a question. but anyway. i guess your image size is big and it causes the network problem. try increasing the time out value or reducing image size.

Comment: i am asking question you can check it please

Comment: this is my question id "46317435". can you please help me dear.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to send messages to users you must know their chatID *(chatID is a long number which is unique for every user in telegram and never changes while username can be changed)* or you must have stored their chatIDs in a database or a file or ...

This means a user must have sent **at least one message to your bot** before this includes the ***/start command***. Then your bot can find out their chatID and using that chatID, you can send whatever you want to that user unless he/she has blocked your bot by pressing **Delete and Stop** button when trying to delete the conversation between him/her and your bot.

Comment: Hello i need some message send on the group in telegram bot using c#? so go how can do that. i have find many link but all the link give ex with chat id. can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can but don't pass `@` symbol, If the username is **@me** pass `"me"` to `SendTextMessageAsync` without passing @.